# Regex recursion and multiple replacements

Tags: python, regex

I have come across a challenge with regex and could use some assistance. Currently working on a script to update syntax on the source file for plugins by using regex.

Situation:

Without looping a regex search until no match, I am attempting to declare multiple variables as int within functions, since the old syntax did not require it.

For example this is the old code, followed by what I then want it to become
`void Split(const char[] variable, test1, char[] variable2, test2, test3) {`

`void Split(const char[] variable, int test1, char[] variable2, int test2, int test3) {`

I have a regex to match a single instance of it here:
`(^\w.*?)(\(|, )([\w_\&]+)(, |\))`
I could then replace with:
`\1\2int \3\4`

Comment: Using regex to parse programming language source is doomed.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just go with creating a loop

Edit:

```
    m = re.search(r"((?:^|\n)\w.*?(?:,\s*|\())(\w+(?:,\s*|\)))", code, re.M)
    while m:
        code = re.sub(r"((?:^|\n)\w.*?(?:,\s*|\())(\w+(?:,\s*|\)))", r"\1int \2", code, re.M)
        m = re.match(r"((?:^|\n)\w.*?(?:,\s*|\())(\w+(?:,\s*|\)))", code, re.M)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to `re.sub`:

```
import re
def update(d) -> str:
  return f' int{d.group()}' if len(re.findall('\w+', d.group())) == 1 else d.group()

s = 'void Split(const char[] variable, test1, char[] variable2, test2, test3)'
new_s = re.sub('(?<=[,\(\)]).*?(?=[,\(\)])', update, s)
```

Output:

```
'void Split(const char[] variable, int test1, char[] variable2, int test2, int test3)'
```